# Convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ when $|z| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Clearly, $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ converges to $0$ when $1 - z^{n_0} = 0$ for some $n_0$.
Suppose $z$ is a complex number with $|z| = 1$ and $1 - z^{n} \ne 0$ for all $n$.
I think $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ diverges, but it is not clear how to prove this.

I know that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ converges to a non-zero number iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -z^n$ converges absolutely. Hence, if $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ converges, it must converge to $0$. It is not clear how to proceed from here.

I would appreciate any hints/pointers for proving (or disproving) that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - z^n)$ is divergent.

Comment: Well it depends on $z$. $z=1$ and the product converges, so you'll have to find more conditions. In fact, if $z$ is any root of unity then the product converges to $0$ after finitely many multiplications

Comment: @FShrike I am assuming $1 - z^n \ne 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: If $z$ is not a root of unity, we have from topological dynamics that the orbit of $z$, i.e. $\{z^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, is dense in the unit circle, so you can find $(1-z^n)$ arbitrarily close to $0$. What this says about convergence I am not sure

Comment: It is usually said that the infinite product converges when the limit of the finite truncations exists and is *non-zero*.

Comment: @FShrike Can you also get that it is equidistributed and then use some kind of probability argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the product converges to a  non-zero number then  $1-z^{n } \to 1$ so $z^{n} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. But $|z^{n}|=1$ so the product does not converge (to a non-zero number) for any $z$ on the unit circle.

[Convergence of an infinite product to $0$ is considered as divergence].

Comment: Shouldn't $z_n$ converge to $0$?

Comment: @Eparoh Sorry@! Answer corrected.